# How to add a text portion under a title image?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to add a text portion under the title section where I can write but when I try to amend the function it keeps adding the text to the title section which I do not want it to do. Is there a solution?

As previously mentioned, I tried to add text below the title section (so I can write things on the webpage). However, when I try to introduce new text, it adds text within the image title, not the

Website Page:

```
import React from 'react';
import '../../App.css';



function AboutMe() {
  return (
   <div className='aboutme'>
    <h1>About Me</h1>
      <div className='aboutmetext'>
        Text
      </div>
  </div>

    
  
  
  );
}

export default AboutMe;
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'PT Sans', sans-serif;
}

.home,
.articles,
.aboutme,
.sign-up {
  display: flex;
  height: 90vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
}

.articles {
  background-image: url('/images/IMG_nappy_936094.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 100px;
}
.aboutmetext{
  color: black;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  justify-content: bottom;
  background-color: white;
  background-position: bottom;
  padding: 4rem;
  
  
}


.aboutme {
  background-image: url('/images/img-7.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 100px;
}

.sign-up {
  background-image: url('/images/img-home.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want things to go from top to bottom with Flexbox, just state it in your container using `flex-direction: column`.

```
.home,
.articles,
.aboutme,
.sign-up {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 90vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 3rem;
}
```

That way, your text is going under the title.
But, please note the following points for your question next time

- Here, we don't have any access to your images, as they are local, so we have only a bare idea of what layout looks like.
- You should use CodeSandbox when you want visual-based, layout issues to be solved, as it allows us to see a real, live version of what you currently have, and to show you our modifications.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem :

- First, you need to add another class for your title:
  `.aboutmeTitle { color: black; font-size: 4rem; /*You can add your style for your title here*/ }`
  and in your "AboutMe()" function add a className into your title like this :
  `<h1 className="aboutmeTitle">About Me</h1>`
- And second, change your aboutme class into this :
  `.aboutme { background-image: url("/images/img-7.jpg"); background-position: center; background-size: cover; color: #fff; font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif; height: 90vh; display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-items: center; justify-content: center; }`

And that's it! I hope it works.

and this is for the [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-lehmann-orn9pp?file=/src/styles.css:814-905)